# Facebook Share and Share on Twitter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

On my landing page I want users to be able to Share on Facebook and Share on Twitter that page with a **particular message**.  I would like to be able to know when they have actually post it on Facebook and/or Twitter (any way to get the callback).

What is the correct way to add a Facebook Share link in Rails? I want to have my own button.

I have taken a look at Koala but I am wondering if it is too much because I just want to be able to Share that landing page. I don't want to provide any kind of authentication or anything more complex.  The only tricky part is that I need to know when they have actually shared.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use external service like sharethis,addthis with some option,

For facebook you can use own way of sharing for this by  registering with facebook app
consider following example

```
<a href="#" onclick='postToFeed("<%= image_url%>","<%= somte text %>"); return false;'>
      <%= image_tag("btn_fb.png" , :alt=>"Facebook") %>
    </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed(img,name) {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      // redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
      link: 'http://url/',
      picture: img,
      name: 'NAME',
      caption: 'CAPTION',
      description: DESCRIPTION
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```